# How to eliminate observations between two tables based on a formula?

Tags: sql, date, sas

I have two tables:

- First table has *name, date, time* and *intraday price* variables. It means there is an *intraday price* for each *name* in a specific *date* and *time*.
- Second table has *name, date* and *daily price* and the *daily price* is *intraday price* aggregation for each *name* and *date*.

I try to write a program which performs the procedure below:

1. It can find same observations by *name* and *date* in two tables and then:
2. If first and last *intraday price* is out of 0.962 and 1.0398 times of *daily price* in last day; then delete all data related to that specific *name* and *date* in *table 1*.

The statement is:

IF first AND last (intraday price for specific name & date) NOT IN [0.962*(daily price of yesterday), 1.0398*(daily price of yesterday)] THEN DELETE.

For instance, consider two tables which are below:

```
data WORK.TABLE1;
infile datalines dsd truncover;
input name:$3. date:DATE9. time:TIME8. intraday_price:32.;
format date DATE9. time TIME8.;
label name="name" date="date" time="time" intraday_price="intraday price";
datalines4;
A,07MAY2008,11:32:41,3
A,07MAY2008,12:32:41,2
A,07MAY2008,13:32:41,1
A,08MAY2008,11:32:41,3.95
A,08MAY2008,12:32:41,3
A,08MAY2008,13:32:41,6
A,08MAY2008,14:32:41,4.01
B,07MAY2008,11:32:41,3.1
B,07MAY2008,12:32:41,1
B,07MAY2008,13:32:41,4
B,07MAY2008,14:32:41,2.9
B,08MAY2008,11:32:41,6
B,08MAY2008,12:32:41,1
B,09MAY2008,11:32:41,5
B,09MAY2008,12:32:41,7
C,07MAY2008,11:32:41,3
C,07MAY2008,12:32:41,2
C,08MAY2008,11:32:41,6.1
C,08MAY2008,12:32:41,3
C,08MAY2008,13:32:41,2
C,09MAY2008,11:32:41,8
C,09MAY2008,12:32:41,2
C,09MAY2008,13:32:41,3
C,09MAY2008,14:32:41,2
;;;;
```

And the table 2 is:

```
data WORK.TABLE2;
infile datalines dsd truncover;
input name:$3. date:DATE9. daily_price:32.;
format date DATE9.;
label name="name" date="date" daily_price="daily price";
datalines4;
A,05MAY2008,3
B,05MAY2008,6
C,05MAY2008,5
A,06MAY2008,5
A,07MAY2008,4
B,06MAY2008,3
B,07MAY2008,4
B,08MAY2008,3
C,06MAY2008,7
C,07MAY2008,6
C,08MAY2008,5
;;;;
```

Please consider that the daily price of yesterday should be used in formula.

So the result is:

```
+------+----------+----------+----------------+
| name |   date   |   time   | intraday price |
+------+----------+----------+----------------+
| B    | 7-May-08 | 11:32:41 |            3.1 |
| B    | 7-May-08 | 12:32:41 |              1 |
| B    | 7-May-08 | 13:32:41 |              4 |
| B    | 7-May-08 | 14:32:41 |            2.9 |
| A    | 8-May-08 | 11:32:41 |           3.95 |
| A    | 8-May-08 | 12:32:41 |              3 |
| A    | 8-May-08 | 13:32:41 |              6 |
| A    | 8-May-08 | 14:32:41 |           4.01 |
| C    | 8-May-08 | 11:32:41 |            6.1 |
| C    | 8-May-08 | 12:32:41 |              3 |
| C    | 8-May-08 | 13:32:41 |              2 |
+------+----------+----------+----------------+
```

Would you please tell me how I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, please clean you data table ( https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ ) ad your expected result and how far you've done now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Shmuel and KurtBremser work in SAS community, the result is:

```
proc sort data=table1; by name date time; run;

proc sort data=table2; by name date; run;

proc sql;
 create table table3 as
 select * from table1, table2
 where table1.name=table2.name and table1.date=table2.date;
quit;

data table2_new;
 set table2;
 by name;
 /* save price of yesterday */
 lag_Price = lag(Price);
 if first.name then lag_Price = .;
run;

data to_delete(keep = name date);
merge table3 (in=in1) 
 table2_new (in=in2);
 by name date;
 retain start_price last_price;

 if in1 and in2; /* deal with obs on both tables only */
 if first.date then start_price = intradayprice;
 if last.date then last_price = intradayprice;
 if last.date then do; 
 min_price = 0.962 * lag_Price;
 max_price = 1.0398 * lag_Price;
 if not (min_price le start_price le max_price) and not (min_price le last_price le max_price)
 then output; 
 end;
run;

data want;
merge table3 /* table2 */
 to_delete (in=indel);
 by name date;
 if not indel;
run;
```

[SAS Community](https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/How-to-eliminate-observations-between-two-tables-based-on-a/m-p/415072#M51968)

Answer (score 0):

This will identify the rows you do not want:

```
    select t1.*
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.date = t2.date
    where (t1.intraday_price < (t2.daily_price*0.962)
       or t1.intraday_price > (t2.daily_price*1.0398)
          )
```

If you place that inside a subquery and then test for EXISTS in that subquery, you are identifying the rows you do not want.

Demo at: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8dfb2/1)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([name] varchar(1), [date] datetime, [time] varchar(8), [intraday_price] decimal(12,2))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([name], [date], [time], [intraday_price])
VALUES
    ('A', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', '11:32:41', 3),
    ('A', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', '12:32:41', 2),
    ('A', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', '13:32:41', 1),
    ('A', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', '11:32:41', 3.95),
    ('A', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', '12:32:41', 3),
    ('A', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', '13:32:41', 6),
    ('A', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', '14:32:41', 4.01),
    ('B', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', '11:32:41', 3.1),
    ('B', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', '12:32:41', 1),
    ('B', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', '13:32:41', 4),
    ('B', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', '14:32:41', 2.9),
    ('B', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', '11:32:41', 6),
    ('B', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', '12:32:41', 1),
    ('B', '2008-05-09 00:00:00', '11:32:41', 5),
    ('B', '2008-05-09 00:00:00', '12:32:41', 7),
    ('C', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', '11:32:41', 3),
    ('C', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', '12:32:41', 2),
    ('C', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', '11:32:41', 6.1),
    ('C', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', '12:32:41', 3),
    ('C', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', '13:32:41', 2),
    ('C', '2008-05-09 00:00:00', '11:32:41', 8),
    ('C', '2008-05-09 00:00:00', '12:32:41', 2),
    ('C', '2008-05-09 00:00:00', '13:32:41', 3),
    ('C', '2008-05-09 00:00:00', '14:32:41', 2)
;



CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([name] varchar(1), [date] datetime, [daily_price] decimal(12,2))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([name], [date], [daily_price])
VALUES
    ('A', '2008-05-05 00:00:00', 3),
    ('B', '2008-05-05 00:00:00', 6),
    ('C', '2008-05-05 00:00:00', 5),
    ('A', '2008-05-06 00:00:00', 5),
    ('A', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', 4),
    ('B', '2008-05-06 00:00:00', 3),
    ('B', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', 4),
    ('B', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', 3),
    ('C', '2008-05-06 00:00:00', 7),
    ('C', '2008-05-07 00:00:00', 6),
    ('C', '2008-05-08 00:00:00', 5)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as (
  select
        *
  from Table1
  where exists (
    select NULL
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.date = t2.date
    where (t1.intraday_price < (t2.daily_price*0.962)
       or t1.intraday_price > (t2.daily_price*1.0398)
          )
    and table1.name = t1.name and table1.date = t1.date and table1.time = t1.time
    )
  )
delete
from cte
;

select * from table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8dfb2/1/0)**:

```
| name |                 date |     time | intraday_price |
|------|----------------------|----------|----------------|
|    A | 2008-05-08T00:00:00Z | 11:32:41 |           3.95 |
|    A | 2008-05-08T00:00:00Z | 12:32:41 |              3 |
|    A | 2008-05-08T00:00:00Z | 13:32:41 |              6 |
|    A | 2008-05-08T00:00:00Z | 14:32:41 |           4.01 |
|    B | 2008-05-07T00:00:00Z | 13:32:41 |              4 |
|    B | 2008-05-09T00:00:00Z | 11:32:41 |              5 |
|    B | 2008-05-09T00:00:00Z | 12:32:41 |              7 |
|    C | 2008-05-09T00:00:00Z | 11:32:41 |              8 |
|    C | 2008-05-09T00:00:00Z | 12:32:41 |              2 |
|    C | 2008-05-09T00:00:00Z | 13:32:41 |              3 |
|    C | 2008-05-09T00:00:00Z | 14:32:41 |              2 |
```

Comment: WITH isn't valid SAS SQL syntax, but it should be close enough that the OP can do their own conversion.

Comment: My bad. Actually didn't notice the sas tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than delete from source tables, create a new dataset filtered for the required records. Specifically, consider an `exists` subquery that selects records according to needed logic.

Below uses a self-join on *table1* to align min and max *time* records within same *name* and *date* into one resultset and checks row-wise both *intraday_price* if they fall within *price* range.

```
proc sql;
   create table newtable as

   select *
   from work.table1 main

   where exists(
     select 1 
     from work.table1 m1    

     inner join work.table1 m2
       on m1.name = m2.name and m1.date = m2.date

     inner join work.table2 t2
       on m1.name = t2.name and m1.date = intnx("day", t2.date, -1) 

     inner join
       (select t.name, t.date, min(t.time) as min_time, max(t.time) as max_time
        from work.table1 t
        group by t.name, t.date
       ) agg
        on m1.name = agg.name and m1.date = agg.date 
        and m1.time = agg.min_time and m2.time = agg.max_time

     where m1.intraday_price between (0.962 * t2.daily_price) and (1.0398 * t2.daily_price)
       and m2.intraday_price between (0.962 * t2.daily_price) and (1.0398 * t2.daily_price)

       and main.name = m1.name and main.date = m1.date);
quit;
```

Comment: The opposite of statement, which is described above, is:
IF first OR last (intraday price for specific name & date) IN [0.962*(daily price of yesterday), 1.0398*(daily price of yesterday)] THEN OUTPUT.

If each conditions which you wrote in your code for making new table, is satisfied, then the final result is corrected. In the other words, There is OR operator between two conditions in your code.

Comment: Indeed, `UNION` usually mirrors `OR`. I have updated query to check that both conditions must satisfy.